# How to insert Data to two tables who has an FK relationship in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i'm trying to learn php and want to insert data to two tables who has an Fk relationship with an form
This is my code:

```
<?php
// gegevens inserten in de database 
require "db.php"; // database connectie 
$message =''; // het bericht laten we eerst leeg 
//checken of alle velden zijn ingevuld
if (isset ($_POST['client_name']) && isset($_POST['phonenumber']) && isset($_POST['tabel']) && isset($_POST['persons']) && isset($_POST['date']) && isset($_POST['time'])){
   $client_name = $_POST['client_name'];
   $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
   $tabel = $_POST['tabel'];
   $persons = $_POST['persons'];
   $date = $_POST['date'];
   $time = $_POST['time'];
   //$sql = "INSERT INTO reserveringen(tabel, date, time, persons) VALUES(:tabel, :date, :time, :persons) INNER JOIN klant (client_name, phonenumber) VALUES(:client_name, :phonenumber) ON reserveringen.client_id = klant.client_id "
   $sql = "INSERT INTO reserveringen(tabel, date, time, persons) VALUES(:tabel, :date, :time, :persons)";
   $sql1= "INSERT INTO klant(client_name, phonenumber) VALUES(:client_name, :phonenumber)";
   $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
   $statement1 = $connection->prepare($sql1);

  if ($statement->execute([':tabel' => $tabel, ':date' => $date, ':time' => $time, ':persons' => $persons]) && $statement1->execute([':client_name' => $client_name, ':phonenumber' => $phonenumber]) ){
       $message = 'Data is succesvol toegevoegd';
   }else{
    $message = 'Data is niet  succesvol toegevoegd';
   }
}
?>
```

can someone help me

Comment: Please, post the code in your question.

Comment: I did i hope you can help me

Comment: Please tag your questionw with the database that you are using. Is this MySQL?

Comment: yes I'm using MySQL

Comment: Hint: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: What is the error when executing the code?

Comment: Thanks guys I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql1= "INSERT INTO klant(client_name, phonenumber) VALUES(:client_name, :phonenumber)";
   $statement1 = $connection->prepare($sql1);
   $statement1->execute([':client_name' => $client_name, ':phonenumber' => $phonenumber]);

   $client_id = $connection->lastInsertId();

   $sql = "INSERT INTO reservation(tabel, date, time, client_id,  persons) VALUES(:tabel, :date, :time, :client_id, :persons)";
   $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
   $statement->execute([':tabel' => $tabel, ':date' => $date, ':time' => $time, ':client_id' => $client_id, ':persons' => $persons]);

   if($statement && $statement1 == true){
    $message = 'Data is succesvol toegevoegd';
   }else{
    $message = 'Data is niet  succesvol toegevoegd';
   } 
}
```